# Aborted connection - Got an error reading communication packets

Tags: mysql, my.cnf, mysql-5.7

I'm using MySQL Community Server `5.7.15-log` and MySQL Connector/ODBC 5.3.6 on Windows 2012 and getting a lot of these messages:

> [Note] Aborted connection X to db: 'Y' user: 'Z' host:
>   'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)

I have `max_allowed_packet` set to `1G`:

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
+--------------------+------------+
| Variable_name      | Value      |
+--------------------+------------+
| max_allowed_packet | 1073741824 |
+--------------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.14 sec)

mysql>
```

---

Any advice?

Comment: How much RAM?  I would not recommend having `max_allowed_packet` higher than 2% of RAM.

Comment: *"Any advice?"*  Any idea what was experienced and what was happening on the other side of the connections at the time of the error?  What error if aby did the client library or calling code see?  I ask that because I assume this message is from the server (not the client) error log, but you might want to make that clear.

Comment: Refer: https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/05/16/mysql-got-an-error-reading-communication-packet-errors/ They explained it very nicely.